# No wpa_supplicant executable

Tags: wifi, raspbian-buster, apt, packages, wpa-supplicant

I'm running Rasbpian 10 (buster) on raspberry pi 3 b+. Where can I find the `wpa_supplicant` binary?

```bsh
$ sudo apt install wpa_supplicant
E: Unable to locate package wpa_supplicant
# Same for wpa and wpa_cli packages
```

The `wpasupplicant` package exists, but it doesn't include the `wpa_supplicant` binary. I'm trying to do some stuff with automating connecting to a router with ssid & password. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct package is `wpasupplicant` and the default install location on Debian Buster for the `wpa_supplicant` binary is `/sbin`. If that location is not in the path already, then you can add it to the path if you would like.

Edit: See @Seamus comment below for context on adding folders to the path

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but your advice may not be the best: "`If that location is not in the path already, add it to the path.`" In general, it's best to stick with the folders the system provides for binaries. For example, that has changed between `buster` and `bullseye` - at least on RPi. On buster there is a folder `/sbin` w/ many executables, but on bullseye only this: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Oct 30 11:09 /sbin -> usr/sbin`

Answer (score 3):

A method that works well for me (better than guessing - or attempting to recall) to find package names is:

```bsh
$ apt-cache search supplicant
argonaut-fuse - Argonaut (modular TFTP/Fuse supplicant)
argonaut-fuse-module-fai - Argonaut (LDAP FAI module for the TFTP/Fuse supplicant)
argonaut-fuse-module-opsi - Argonaut (OPSI module for the TFTP/Fuse supplicant)
connman - Intel Connection Manager daemon
connman-dev - Development files for connman
connman-vpn - Intel Connection Manager daemon - VPN daemon
dhcpcd-gtk - GTK+ frontend for dhcpcd and wpa_supplicant
libwpa-client-dev - development files for WPA/WPA2 client support (IEEE 802.11i)
wpagui - graphical user interface for wpa_supplicant
wpasupplicant - client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
$
$ # sometimes best to pipe to a pager & seaarch in the pager:
$ apt-cache search supplicant | less

/wpa

dhcpcd-gtk - GTK+ frontend for dhcpcd and wpa_supplicant
libwpa-client-dev - development files for WPA/WPA2 client support (IEEE 802.11i)
wpagui - graphical user interface for wpa_supplicant
wpasupplicant - client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
```

Comment: Also useful working examples in this case: `apt-file search wpa_supplicant` (finds all packages containing a file with basename `wpa_supplicant`) and `apt search wpa | grep -i supplicant` (finds all packages with `wpa` and `supplicant`, both case insensitive, in package names or short descriptions).